# Не запускается программно скопированное приложение

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Попробую объяснить как можно более понятно.

Сделал я консольное приложение, которое запускается основным для обновления (примитивная update-system).

Работает оно всё следующим образом:

**основное приложение:**

1. работает в штатном режиме и каждые N-времени проверяет не изменилась ли дата создания exe-файла
   в удаленном хранилище;
2. если дата текущего exe-файла и exe-файла из каталога обновлений не
   совпадают, то основное приложение запускает консольное;

**консольное приложение:**

1. убивает процесс основного;
2. проверяет на месте ли все необходимые директории;
3. удаляет все файлы из текущей директории;
4. копирует все файлы из каталога обновлений в текущий каталог;
5. создает ярлык для исполняемого файла основного приложения на рабочем
   столе если нет;
6. запускает исполняемый файл скопированного обновления.

Вот код:

```
if (Directory.Exists(updatePath))
{
        if (Directory.Exists(currentPath))
        {
                DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(currentPath);
                foreach (FileInfo file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
                {
                        file.Delete();
                }
                foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
                {
                        directory.Delete(true);
                }
        }
        else
        {
                Console.WriteLine("Create current directory " + currentPath);
                Directory.CreateDirectory(currentPath);
        }
        DirectoryInfo updir = new DirectoryInfo(updatePath);
        foreach (FileInfo file in updir.GetFiles())
        {
                file.CopyTo(currentPath + @"\" + file.Name, true);
        }
        foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in updir.GetDirectories())
        {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(currentPath + @"\" + directory.Name);
                foreach (FileInfo infile in directory.GetFiles())
                {
                        infile.CopyTo(currentPath + @"\" + infile.Name,true);
                }
        }
        CreateShortcut();                              
}
else
{
        Console.WriteLine("Update folder didn't found!");
}
Process iStartProcess = new Process();
iStartProcess.StartInfo.FileName = currentPath + @"\<основной ЕХЕ>";
iStartProcess.Start();
```

*Загвоздка в том, что код отрабатывает на ура. Всё копируется и даже процесс "стартуется". Но вот cама скопированная программа запускается и тут же убивается. Как? Что происходит? Не понятно. Исходный exe в полном порядке. Запускается и работает. А вот скопированный программно через консольное приложение - не хочет. При этом он на мгновение появляется в диспетчере задач и моментально пропадает оттуда.*

Буду рад любым советам! Спасибо.

Comment: в Event Viewer ошибки есть?

Comment: @tCode "Процесс был завершен из-за необработанного исключения. Сведения об исключении: System.IO.FileNotFoundException" - вот это нашел. Проверил пошагово, что происходит. Получается что я копировал файлы не туда =/

Протупил. Простите. Спасибо за совет с Event Viewer)))

Comment: кстати запускать процесс можно в одну строчку `Process iStartProcess = Process.Start(currentPath + @"\<основной ЕХЕ>");`